# How can I capture data coming into my Android app from the standard input (stdin)?

Tags: android, stdin

I am writing an app that uses an external USB barcode/RFID scanner. The scanner is a standard HID, and works well on my Android devices. I plug it in, hit the scan button, and data pops up in a text editing app. The same can be said for a standard USB keyboard. I plug it in, start typing, and data shows up in a text editing app.

Here is where I need assistance. What I need to do is manipulate the data coming into my app, from the scanner or external keyboard, before I can place it into the correct form fields of the app.

At this point, I thought I could just intercept the data at the standard input, so this is what I came up with:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/scan_data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText scannedInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.scan_data);

    BufferedReader scanner = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String buffer;

    while((buffer = scanner.readLine()) != null){
        sBuilder.append(buffer);
    }

    String[] dataPoints = sBuilder.toString().split("\u003D|\u0026");

    scannedInput.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    scannedInput.setTextSize(34f);
    scannedInput.setText(dataPoints[0]); // or dataPoints[1], dataPoints[2], etc.
}
```

I wrote this, hooked up my scanner, and scanned an RFID tag. To my surprise, the entire scanned string showed up in my EditText field, and not just a part. After some debugging, I found out I could delete all code after `setContentView()` and the entire string still shows up in my EditText field.

So, what I need to know is, how I can capture the stdin from any external source (e.g., scanner, keyboard, etc.), and manipulate it before placing it where I want it (form field, database, etc.).

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't access stdin, there is no such animal in Android for apps.  The text is being injected into the active `EditText` because the RFID / USB device you are using is presenting itself as a HID device.  These are automatically picked up by the Android subsystem as an input source and their input routed to the active view as if it came from a keyboard.

All is not lost, however.  What you can do is attach a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` and manipulate the text in the `Editable`:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.whatever_your_id);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {
            //  Make your changes to 's' here, carefully as your changes will
            //  cause this method to be called again!
        }

        @Override
        void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //  Nothing to do here
        }

        @Override
        void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //  Nothing to do here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. A quick question, though. When I scan a tag, let's say the code is "0123456789", then **s** becomes: "0" then "01" then "012" then "0123" then "01234", then "012345" ... and so on. Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Comment: That happens because each character added is changing the `Editable`.  Does the scanner send a character terminator, such as a newline?  Since you were trying to use `readline()`, I'm assuming it does.  If so, you could key off of that and only make your manipulations after it arrives.  The drawback here is that the text field will show the unmodified string before your final modified one is set.  The more complicated approach would be to have a small state machine which takes the modified input and adds it to an instance variable; after newline arrives make your changes and set to `s`.

Comment: No ... no newline character at all. The input just stops. If I were to scan a new barcode/RFID then it would start printing where the first one left off.

Comment: Also, the input string length will always be variable; I have no way of knowing beforehand how long it will be. Is there something I can key off of to tell me when the TextWatcher isn't reading any more input?

Comment: The `TextWatcher` doesn't read the input, it is notified of the input as it arrives asynchronously from the HID device.  If you want to manipulate it based off of so much "idle" time, you'd have to get more elaborate and have some kind of `Timer` running which could then update the text.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll keep playing around with it to see if I can get it to work. On a side note, I can't believe that there is no elegant, straight-forward way to do what I need to do. With all of the point of sale, inventory, medical, etc. uses for Android and input devices, you would think that Google would have given us a better tool. Kind of short-sighted on their part IMHO.