# Getting Error While Read User Input in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, user-input

I'm trying to create search fiture without action bar use autocompletetextview. So far, the layout and suggestion is working, but when I type to search, any character I typed giving same result and it doesnt give suggest based on text I typed. And I check it again, that my input was "d", so I change it to:

```
val userInput = readLine()!!
insertData(userInput, 10, "id/suggest")
```

In this time, I'm getting error. Here's my log

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.postrequest, PID: 17116
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.postrequest/com.example.postrequest.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encodings with multiple chars per byte are not supported
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encodings with multiple chars per byte are not supported
> at kotlin.io.ConsoleKt.readLine(Console.kt:157)
> at kotlin.io.ConsoleKt.readLine(Console.kt:154)
> at com.example.postrequest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:26)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

So, help me how to solve that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `readLine` on Android in the first place. This method reads from the standard input stream, which makes sense in a console application, but not on Android, as that's not the way your user is interacting with the app (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314006/4465208) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42543106/4465208)).

Instead, you probably want to create an `EditText` on your UI that the user can type into, and read the value from that using `getText`.

---

The literal explanation for your exception: from looking at the [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/7b08f6f8f17063b089f976551ea7a691d933cece/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Console.kt#L146) is that [`readLine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) uses the decoder returned by `Charset.defaultCharset().newDecoder()` in its implementation, and requires this `CharsetDecoder` to operate with a single char per byte - the implementation returned on Android happens to have a maximum of 2 chars per byte, hence the `require` call in `readLine`'s implementation throws the exception.

Comment: Can I create suggestion list with EditText?

Comment: [`AutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) is already an `EditText` itself, so if you need the value currently in it, you can call `getText` on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to read from the console on Android, you can do:

```
val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
userInput = scanner.nextLine()
```